# Get value from last row in sap

Tags: gridview, sap-gui

I have one problem with getting value from Sap.
I set MyGrid as here:
`Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(0, "NETWR")` and stad of 0 I would have somethin as "Lastrow with value"
How can I set for column (Name of column "NETWR")  get value from last row with value?
picture will say more. [ROWS][1]

So I already done with this.

```
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
With myGrid
   .firstVisibleRow = .RowCount - 4
   Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(.RowCount - 4, "NETWR")
  End With
```

But still need help, what Can I use for ignore variable just for tha part of code?

````
Dim ses As Object
i= 2
Do
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VKORG-LOW").Text = "SOME"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "ZGBSTD"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "ZGBSTD"
Dim myGrid As Object                                ' here I need ignore variable
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")           ' here I need ignore variable
With myGrid                                 ' here I need ignore variable
   .firstVisibleRow = .RowCount - 4                     ' here I need ignore variable
   Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(.RowCount - 4, "NETWR") ' Here have to stay variable for Cells(i, 2) 
                                        ' but variable can't chnge RowCount- 4
End With
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
i = i + 1
Loop

'here is rest of code to end connection with SAP ```

Thank you 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaPdK.png
````

Comment: what is grid? what technology do you use? grid is just a generic word

Comment: [This](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/04/02/tip-write-each-table-with-sap-gui-scripting-to-a-csv-file/) might help you in getting an idea how to get data from an ALV grid

Comment: It's session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell") from SAP

Comment: You have asked this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71232489/variable-i-i-1-makes-a-mess-with-a-part-of-the-code-rowcount-4-how-to-ig) whose answer has solved your issue, so I suggest that you delete this current one, to keep Stack Overflow the cleanest possible.

Comment: I would like to delete this question but I can't. U have to delete your comment with "Duplicate question" . Then I can do that.