# variable I = i + 1 makes a mess with a part of the code (Rowcount - 4) How to ignore a variable for this part?

Tags: excel, variables, sap-gui

My variable doing mess with my part of code `(Rowcount - 4, NETPR)`. Can I ignore this variable for this part and how?

```
'here is code to connect SAP

Dim ses As Object
i= 2
Do
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VKORG-LOW").Text = "SOME"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "ZGBSTD"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "ZGBSTD"
Dim myGrid As Object                                ' here I need ignore variable
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")           ' here I need ignore variable
With myGrid                                 ' here I need ignore variable
   .firstVisibleRow = .RowCount - 4                     ' here I need ignore variable
   Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(.RowCount - 4, "NETWR") ' Here have to stay variable for Cells(i, 2) 
                                        ' but variable can't chnge RowCount- 4
End With
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
i = i + 1
Loop

'here is rest of code to end connection with SAP
```

UPDATE
here is pcs what i think [![Last rows][1]][1]
Here is my code :

```
J=1
Do                                               'LAYOUT 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "ZGBSTD"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "ZGBSTD"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&FILTER"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").Text = "SOME"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/btn%_%%DYN001_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").Text ="SOME"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").caretPosition = 12
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
 myGrid.currentCellColumn = "NETWR"
 myGrid.selectColumn "NETWR" 'Just filtering data (COLUMN NETWR)
 LastRow = myGrid.RowCount - 1
 
Do
'Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - 3, "NETWR")
If myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR") <> " " Then
Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR")
Exit Do
End If
j = j + 1
Loop
```

And i would like to pasting the last row with value to excel

Comment: no need to ask same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219024/get-value-from-last-row-in-sap) again, just edit your first one and answer people requests.

Comment: @SandraRossi But now that it's here, and the OP's question was answered (and solved), do we keep the thread?  I suppose that might be a question for Meta.

Comment: Yes of course It does answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the program is supposed to do overall, but first I would clean up a bit and then see what's next.

for example:

```
'here is code to connect SAP

Dim ses As Object
Dim myGrid As Object
i= 2
Do
 session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VKORG-LOW").Text = "SOME"
 Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")            
 myGrid.currentCellColumn = "ZGBSTD"
 myGrid.selectColumn "ZGBSTD"
 LastRow = myGrid.RowCount - 1 
 'every single value of the table 
 Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i - 2, "NETWR")
 'or always the last value 
 'Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - 3, "NETWR")
 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
 i = i + 1
 'without an exit, the loop runs indefinitely 
 if i - 2 > LastRow then exit do 
Loop

'here is rest of code to end connection with SAP
```

Regards, ScriptMan

My opinion to the update:

```
'**J=1**??
'**new**
i = 2
'**new**
Do                                               'LAYOUT 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "ZGBSTD"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "ZGBSTD"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&FILTER"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").Text = "SOME"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/btn%_%%DYN001_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").Text ="SOME"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").caretPosition = 12
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
 myGrid.currentCellColumn = "NETWR"
 myGrid.selectColumn "NETWR" 'Just filtering data (COLUMN NETWR)
 LastRow = myGrid.RowCount - 1
'**new**
j = 1 
'**new**
 Do
  'Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - 3, "NETWR")
  '** "" = empty 
  If myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR") <> "" Then
   Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR")
   Exit Do
  End If
  j = j + 1
 Loop
'**new** 
i = i + 1
'if i - 2 > LastRow then exit do
Loop
'**new**
```

Comment: I changed some lines and now it works perfectly. So thank you for helping me :) But I'm getting a new problem that I have to solve. The value I need is sometimes on the last 3rd line and on the 4th line. So I need something like `IF myGrid.getcellvalue(i - 2, "NETWR")="" Then Sheets("AB"). cells(i, 2). Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i - 3, "NETWR")`

Comment: Maybe better say, I need last row with value

Comment: To forestall any other possibilities, I would represent the search for a value at the end of the table as follows: `j = 0 /
do /
if myGrid.GetCellValue(lastRow - j, "NETWR")<> ""  then /
   Sheets("AB"). cells(i, 2). Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(lastRow - j, "NETWR") /
   exit do /
end if /
j = j + 1 /
loop /
'or for the other case /                 j = 0 /
do /
if myGrid.GetCellValue(i - 2 - j, "NETWR")<> ""  then /
   Sheets("AB"). cells(i, 2). Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(i - 2 - j, "NETWR") /
   exit do /
end if /
j = j + 1 /
loop`

Comment: I will try this code and let u know, Thank you

Comment: Can I paste this code in already existing loop?

Comment: Of course, but please in the right place.

Comment: Still does not work I, if is true value on last 3rd row then It's ok, but when is value on last 4th  then I'm getting empty row . Here is what I did `J=1 Do
'Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - 3, "NETWR")
If myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR") <> " " Then
Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR")
Exit Do
End If
j = j + 1
Loop`

Comment: I think that this row does not worikg good `If myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR") <> " " Then`

Comment: If you don't see the whole program, it's hard to judge.

Comment: Or I would test like this: `J=1 Do If myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR") <> "" Then Sheets("AB").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(LastRow - j, "NETWR") Exit Do End If j = j + 1 Loop `                                                                                    "" => This is not a space but an empty string

Comment: I have been working on it .